# moving camera effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I've to build a website for one real estate developer. Now he wants to put walk through of building/apartment. Is there any way to implement this using jquery like a visitor can see layout of building or apartment as he moves a mouse cursor. Such as moving camera in 3d object. I don't want to use video or swf object. Plz help me.

Comment: Even if it's possible, it's going to be 10 times the work using jquery rather than flash.

Comment: ok but swf object creates problem in SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check out [jQuery Virtual Tour.](http://www.openstudio.fr/jQuery-virtual-tour.html?lang=en)

Here is a demo:

http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery-virtual-tour/

I've actually seen this in production in a couple different places.

Comment: You can do panoramic but probably not a walk through.

Comment: You can also do a walkthrough if you check the demo.

Comment: Oh i see. You can click the room that you want to go to and then it does a panoramic in there. Thanks for proving me wrong.

Comment: thanks 2 both of u. it's a gr8 plugin. is it possible to move forward & backward ?

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no functionality to add "fluid motion" aka emulating walking. However this doesn't surprise me because that task really wasn't made for javascript.

Comment: Truthfully my answer is to checkout flash solutions as those can handle such tasks.

Comment: ok thanks mike. but i've to use only jquery as swf creates problem in SEO

Comment: mike can u tell me to use this plugin which type of images do I require so that I can ask to my client

Comment: @valay swf only creats problems for SEO if it replaces text and images, or if the entire site is created in flash. For the type of walkthrough that you are looking for, flash would be your best option as it will not hinder the SEO of your site.